# Counting the number of Lemmas in the Given Corpus

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am a newbie in the Natural Language Processing.

Currently I am working on one Corpus and trying to implement bigram model using the add-one smoothing..

According to the Add-one Smoothing method

[image: Add-one smoothing formula]

Here V is the vocabulary of the Corpus i.e. Total number of word types in the Corpus.
But while counting the word types I am considering the words in same stem as single word. i.e. cats and cat will be the same while counting.

I want to know if there is any method or algorithm that can help me with finding the lemmas in the Corpus.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to go about finding a lemma given a word?  If that's the case, then you might want to look at the [WordNet lemmatizer in NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/wordnet.html).  Additionally the [ClearNLP](http://www.clearnlp.com/) library has a morphological analyzer which is roughly equivalent to the WordNet lemmatizer.  In both cases you will need to run a Part of Speech (POS) Tagger first, so that the lemmatizer has the proper hints for how to stem the word down.

Comment: I looked for WordNet lemmatizer in NLTK and it helped me to find the number of Lemmas.

Answer (score 0):

I had written a small Python script to get the Lemma Count as follows:

```
import nltk
import re
wnl = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()

corpusFile = input("Ener the Corpus file name with complete path\n")
LemmaList = []
fopen = open(corpusFile, 'r',encoding='UTF-8')
for line in fopen:
 line = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z ]+", '', line)
 LemmaList = LemmaList+[wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in line.split()]
print(len(set(LemmaList)))
```